# Netty convert HttpRequest to ByteBuf

Tags: java, netty

In my application I need to receive a byte array on a socket, parse it as a `HttpRequest` to perform some check and, if the checks passes, get back to the byte array and do some more work.

The application is based on NETTY (this is a requirement).

My first idea was to create a pipeline like this:

1. `HttpRequestDecoder` (decode from `ByteBuf` to `HttpRequest`)
2. `MyHttpRequestHandler` (do my own checks on the `HttpRequest`)
3. `HttpRequestEncoder` (encode the `HttpRequest` to a `ByteBuf`)
4. `MyButeBufHandler` (do my works with the `ByteBuf`)

However the `HttpRequestEncoder` extends the `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter` so it doesn't get called for the inbound data.

How can I accomplish this task?
It would be nice to avoid decoding and re-encoding the request.

Regards,
Massimiliano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `EmbeddedChannel` in `MyHttpRequestHandler`.

EmbeddedChannel ch = new EmbeddedChannel(new HttpRequestEncoder());
   ch.writeOutbound(msg);
   ByteBuf encoded = ch.readOutbound();

You'll have to keep the `EmbeddedChannel` as a member variable of `MyHttpRequestEncoder` because `HttpRequestEncoder` is stateful.  Also, please close the `EmbeddedChannel` when you finished using it (probably in your `channelInactive()` method.)

Comment: With that code I get an error: 

`io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected message type: LastHttpContent$1 
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:107)`

Comment: My fault. I forgot to keep EmbeddedChannel as a member variable. Now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just had to encode and decode some HttpObjects and struggled a bit with it.
The hint that the decoder/encoder are stateful is very valuable.

That's why I thought I'll add my findings here. Maybe it's helpful to someone else.

I declared an RequestEncoder and a ResponseDecoder as a class member, but it still didn't work correctly. Until I remembered that the specific handler I was using the en/decoders within was shared...

That's how I got it to work in the end. My sequenceNr is to distinct between the different requests. I create one encoder and one decoder per request and save them in a HashMap. With my sequenceNr, I'm able to always get the same decoder/encoder for the same request. Don't forget to close and remove the de/encoder channels from the Map after processing the LastContent object.

```
@ChannelHandler.Sharable
public class HttpTunnelingServerHandler extends ChannelDuplexHandler {
private final Map<Integer, EmbeddedChannel> decoders = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer, EmbeddedChannel>());
private final Map<Integer, EmbeddedChannel> encoders = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer, EmbeddedChannel>());
.
.
//Encoding
if (!encoders.containsKey(currentResponse.getSequenceNr())) {
        encoders.put(currentResponse.getSequenceNr(), new EmbeddedChannel(new HttpResponseEncoder()));
    }
    EmbeddedChannel encoderChannel = encoders.get(currentResponse.getSequenceNr());
    encoderChannel.writeOutbound(recievedHttpObject);
    ByteBuf encoded = (ByteBuf) encoderChannel.readOutbound();
.
.
//Decoding
if (!decoders.containsKey(sequenceNr)) {
        decoders.put(sequenceNr, new EmbeddedChannel(new HttpRequestDecoder()));
        }
        EmbeddedChannel decoderChannel = decoders.get(sequenceNr);
        decoderChannel.writeInbound(bb);
        HttpObject httpObject = (HttpObject) decoderChannel.readInbound();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the put the EmbeddedChannel as the handler channel's attribute, instead of HashMap. Isn't it the same what you claim to solve the stateful encoder/decoder?

```java
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
      ctx.channel().attr(EMBEDED_CH).set( new EmbeddedChannel(new HttpRequestDecoder()));
      super.channelActive(ctx);
}
    
@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
      EmbeddedChannel embedCh = ctx.channel().attr(EMBEDED_CH).get();
      if (embedCh != null) {
          embedCh.close();
      }

      super.channelInactive(ctx);
}
```